# Why do the exp commands are getting conflicted which I have in react native and oracle?

Tags: oracle, reactjs, react-native

I am using expo to create react native project , i installed npm package for that using the following command.

```
npm install exp --global
```

now i want to create a project with the following command.

```
exp init my-project
```

but i also have oracle installed which has an exp command for export purposes , now the npm exp is conflicting with exp command or npm package

Please give me some solutions

Thanks

Comment: Try to create an alias - alias exp='/path_to_exp/exp' . For environments using oracle this alias shouldn't be set.

Comment: Remove Oracle's `bin` directory from your PATH. Or put the "expo" before the Oracle path